# How to convert vertex colors to materials

Tags: materials, vertex-colors, conversion, obj

Title says it all

How do I convert vertex colors into materials?

I need this because .OBJ doesn't export the vertex colors with it

it doesn't need to be 100% accurate, if there were dark red and bright red then it'd assign something like normal red as the material(so if there are like 500 different colors per faces it wouldn't make 500 materials cuz it's inefficient instead it'd just round to the nearest color)

and no, im not planning on using textures

Comment: If anyone's interested, here is what I used
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcegkL96CQo

Answer (score 1):

This is thankfully much easier than I originally thought it was. Vertex colors can be accessed with the [vertex color input node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/vertex_color.html). :-D

Comment: but when I export it the vertex color is gone

Comment: Hmm. Have you looked into baking to image textures?